# Is there any way to delete duplicates value in one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name deployment in which show the id of the deployed personal base on their task as columns the problem is 1 person can be deployed in multiple task and when I select the table is show as followed:

```
date | task1 | task2 | task3 | task4 
-----+-------+-------+-------+------
fri  + 5046  + 5048  + 5048  + 5048
sat  + 5046  + 5049  + 5048  + 5048
sun  + 5045  + 5047  + 5047  + 5049
```

I wanted to get the ids of personals in one date with out the duplicate as showed:

```
date | ids
-----+----
fri  + 5046 ,5048  
sat  + 5046 ,5048 ,5049
sun  + 5045 ,5047 ,5049
```

The only way I manage to it is to write a function as showed:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Idsdup
( @date date )
returns
nvarchar (max)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Listid = nvarchar (max)
SELECT @Listid = concat( ts.pert1_id, ';' , ts.pert2_id, ';' , ts.pert3_id, ';' , ts.pert4_id) FROM  deployment AS ts WHERE ts.date = @date

DECLARE @ParsedList TABLE
(
Item nvarchar(MAX)
)
INSERT into @ParsedList (Item)
SELECT distinct value  from string_split(@Listid , ',')
DECLARE @rList nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @rlist = (select STRING_AGG(item,';') from @ParsedList)

RETURN @rlist
END
```

Then select liked showed:

```
select dp.date, dbo.Idsdup( dp.date) from deployment as dp
```

Comment: share your tried query

Comment: I assume the number of tasks ranges from 1 to max columns permitted? Search for mysql unpivot and reconsider the table design. AND what do you mean by DELETE you appear to only want to know which personel have been engaged in  unspecified task(s) by date.

Comment: Your published code looks like sql-server/t-sql..if so you should edit the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi-line table value function would be a poor way to do this; it'll be awfully slow. An easier way would be to use a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot the data and get the `DISTINCT` values from that. Then you can simply aggregate the string using `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT V.[date],
       STRING_AGG(T.Task,' ,') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.Task) AS ids
FROM (VALUES('fri ',5046 ,5048 ,5048 ,5048),
            ('sat ',5046 ,5049 ,5048 ,5048),
            ('sun ',5045 ,5047 ,5047 ,5049))V(date,task1,task2,task3,task4)
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT t.task
                  FROM (VALUES(task1),(task2),(task3),(task4))t(task)) T
GROUP BY V.[date];
```